# Xamarin forms - Second image in background

Tags: xaml, layout, xamarin.forms

I would like to achieve something similar to this:

[image]

I already set BackgroundImage = xxx in XAML for the gradient background. But i would like to add another picture (like the mailbox) to be between the background and the pink stacklayouts. So when i scroll the picture won't move (just as gradient background), the rest will.

Tried [this solution](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/60848/multiple-backgrounds-or-one-image-on-top-of-other), it works for background but as i have defined all my elements in xaml and not code behind, it displays only the background.

Basically i would like to mix the solution above and my elements in XAML.
Something similar to this (which isn't possible to do): `Content += mainLayout;`

I reproduced something similar but the picture move with the rest if i scroll. Tried to put the picture in a relative layout but it have no effect.

XAML:

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="0">
        <Image Source="mailbox.png" Scale="1.3"/>

        <StackLayout Padding="15">
            <StackLayout Margin="5" BackgroundColor="#E6fa175b">
                <Label Text="CONTACT" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Large" Margin="10"/>
                <Entry x:Name="mail_Name" Placeholder="Prénom Nom" PlaceholderColor="White" WidthRequest="150" Margin="10"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Margin="5" BackgroundColor="#E6fa175b" >
                <Entry x:Name="mail_Email" Placeholder="Email" PlaceholderColor="White"  WidthRequest="150" Margin="10"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Margin="5" BackgroundColor="#E6fa175b">
                <Label Text="Votre message" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" Margin="10,3" HeightRequest="30" />
                <Editor x:Name="mail_Msg" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="80" Margin="10"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <Button x:Name="btn_send_mail" Clicked="Click_Send" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Envoyer" BackgroundColor="LightSteelBlue"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please, share the relevant code to your question, or a [mcve]. Thus we'll be able to give you an objective and complete answer.

Comment: I added the code i wrote at this time, idk if it's what you meant but it will illustrate more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Xamarin.Forms' built-in layouts like `Grid`, `AbsoluteLayout`, and `RelativeLayout` allow overlapping views. Just use one of them and you can do it.

In your case, I believe is enough to set the scrollview over the image.

Like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
           HorizontalOptions= "CenterAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="Start"
           Source="mailbox.png" Scale="1.3"/>

    <ScrollView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <StackLayout Spacing="0" 
                     Padding="0">
            <StackLayout Padding="15">
                <StackLayout Margin="5" 
                             BackgroundColor="#E6fa175b">
                    <Label Text="CONTACT" 
                           TextColor="White" 
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                           FontSize="Large" 
                           Margin="10"/>
                    <Entry x:Name="mail_Name" 
                           Placeholder="Prénom Nom" 
                           PlaceholderColor="White" 
                           WidthRequest="150" 
                           Margin="10"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Margin="5" 
                             BackgroundColor="#E6fa175b" >
                    <Entry x:Name="mail_Email" 
                           Placeholder="Email" 
                           PlaceholderColor="White"  
                           WidthRequest="150" 
                           Margin="10"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Margin="5" 
                             BackgroundColor="#E6fa175b">
                    <Label Text="Votre message" 
                           FontSize="Medium" 
                           TextColor="White" 
                           Margin="10,3" 
                           HeightRequest="30" />
                    <Editor x:Name="mail_Msg" 
                            WidthRequest="150" 
                            HeightRequest="80" 
                            Margin="10"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <Button x:Name="btn_send_mail" 
                    Clicked="Click_Send" 
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    Text="Envoyer" 
                    BackgroundColor="LightSteelBlue"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome, that works! Never thought about using the Grid this way.

Comment: @Grounch Excellent. You can use `AbsoluteLayout` or `RelativeLayout` too. The general rule is that the last item declared on `XAML` is the topmost on the layout view. I think grid is simpler